# Assigning IP address to a docker container does not work in Mac OS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When using Windows 10 via WSL and run the command below, I am able to successful execute the command. But when using Docker for Mac (Ventura 13.4.1), it returns an error.

Docker for Mac version: 4.21.1

Here's the command:

`docker run -p 192.168.1.10:8080:80 nginx`

Here's the error:
`docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 192.168.1.10:8080 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 192.168.1.10:8080: bind: can't assign requested address. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:`

The same happnes when I run using `docker-compose.yml`. Below is the yaml file.

```
version: '3'

networks:
    test_net:
        name: test_net
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
services:
    test_api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: .docker/site.dockerfile
        container_name: test_api
        ports:
            - 192.168.1.10:80:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        networks:
            test_net:
                aliases:
                    - "api.test-local.com"
```

Comment: `-p 192.168.1.10:8080:80` instructs docker to forward host `192.168.1.10:8080` to `80` on the container.  192.168.1.10 is *probably* the LAN IP of the windows machine.  The Mac has a different IP.  The portable way to do it would be to just say `-p 8080:80`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to assign IP address because I am working on multiple projects. Not assigning an IP means it will run on the localhost which is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: That's not correct.  ["By default the -p flag binds the specified port to all interfaces on the host machine."](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#connect-using-network-port-mapping).  Docker containers typically have their own IPs on the internal network, so you don't have to give them different IPs, you have to map unique ports on the host to make them accessible at the same time.

Comment: then without assigning an IP, if I have multiple projects using port 80 and 3306, would that mean I need to have each project point port 80 and 3306 to a different port? say 80:81 and 3306:3307?

Comment: this is because if I remove the IP address on the Ports and I run `docker-compose up -d` on other projects that also uses the same ports, it returns this error "Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint test_api (3f58f772e050aa7d6c582cc12703814110e09cee5a927eb1216e337a49946641): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated"

Comment: yes, only one thing can listen on a particular port.  assigning unique port is the simplest solution.  docker can also automatically choose a port, but then the ports are random and you need to look them up with `docker ps ` each time, so folks don't usually leave port choice to docker.

Comment: what if I want to assign an IP so on the `/etc/hosts` file I could assign a host name per IP?

Comment: Then you'd have to have the same IPs added to interface(s) on each computer that ran the stack, and `docker run` would have to specify the appropriate IP.  `/etc/hosts` is merely a way of turning dns names into IPs, you also have to actually assign that IP to an interface.  Now you're moving more of the automation outside of docker and have to find some other way of setting those IPs for each environment.